# Optimality condition in constrained convex optimization

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-optimization

Consider a constrained optimization problem
$$
\underset{\beta\in\mathbb R^p}{\text{minimize}}f(\beta)\quad\text{such that}\ \beta\in\mathcal C,
$$
where $f:\mathbb R^p\to\mathbb R$ is a convex objective function to be minimized, and $\mathcal C\subset\mathbb R^p$ is a convex constraint set.

> When the cost function is differentiable, a necessary and sufficient condition for a vector $\beta^*\in\mathcal C$ to be a global optimum is that
>   $$
> \langle\nabla f(\beta^*),\beta-\beta^*\rangle\ge0
> $$
>   for all $\beta\in\mathcal C$.

I am looking for an intuitive explanation of this condition.

Using the first-order condition for convexity, we see that this condition is indeed sufficient. The condition also implies that the angle between $\nabla f(\beta^*)$ and $\beta-\beta^*$ is acute for all $\beta\in\mathcal C$. But why does this mean that $\beta^*$ is a minimzer?

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: If $\nabla f=0$, it is trivial that you have a global optimum. Otherwise, it means that the directional derivative toward any point in $\mathcal C$ is nonnegative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a minimizer, the directional derivative in any feasible direction must be nonnegative. Otherwise, we would not be at a minimizer. (Because then we could decrease the objective function value by moving a bit in a feasible direction for which the directional derivative is negative.)

Comment: A very nice argument (+1)! I am trying to understand why we take $\beta-\beta^*$. Somehow I would like to take $\beta^*+\beta$ (we are at $\beta^*$ and we move in the direction of $\beta$). Why do we take $\beta-\beta^*$?

Comment: $\beta - \beta^*$ is a vector that points from $\beta^*$ to $\beta$. So it's a vector that points in a feasible direction.